# Is it possible to show/hide textformfields in Flutter based on a Checkbox

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to use a checkbox to show/hide 2 textformfields in Flutter. I have tried the below code thinking that it would use the state of the checkbox to display the fields. but this does not work.

The Checkbox itself does toggle between true and false but there is no change in the layout.

```
CheckboxListTile(
                              title: Text("Do you want to update your price?"),

                      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                          value: priceupdate_value,
                          onChanged: (bool priceupdateValue) {
                            setState(() {


                              priceupdate_value = priceupdateValue;

                            });
                            if(priceupdate_value == true){

                              Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  TextFormField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: 'New Price',
                                    ),

                                  ),
                                  TextFormField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: 'Update Other Information',
                                    ),

                                  ),

                                ],
                              );

                            }

                          },

                    ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some small changes and it's ok.
I hope it will suit for you.

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      if (priceupdate_value)
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'New Price',
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Update Other Information',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text("Do you want to update your price?"),
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
        value: priceupdate_value,
        onChanged: (bool priceupdateValue) {
          setState(() {
            priceupdate_value = priceupdateValue;
          });
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

You can copy-paste the code here to the dartpad.dev and check it instantly: https://gist.github.com/malibayram91/0ba5c3c5fbdb89f9c2a6a4ec3333d070

Comment: thanks this worked. only difference I made was to put the CheckboxListTile as the first child as I wanted the textboxes below the checkbox. thanks so much. just for my own understanding, why do i not need to specify `true` in the `if` statement?

Comment: You don't need to specify booleans (true-false) in if statements because they can not be anything else

Comment: This solution has one drawback though :S if the boolean is false then there is no space allocated for the InputFields leading to the unexpected jumping around of the Checkbox widget :O

Comment: Noted and thanks for the answers. what you referring to is essentially dependent on how i would implement in Native with `View.INVISIBLE` or `view.GONE`

Answer (score 16):

Wrap it with a visibility widget:

```
Visibility(
    visible: priceupdate_value,
    child: TextFormField(...),
)
```

And you have to create your Column Widget outside the onPressed Method (Like wrap your CheckBoxTileListWidget with a column Widget and then under children add Both your CheckBoxTileList and your TextInputField)

Something like

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
        Visibility(
            visible: priceupdate_value,
            child: TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Update Other Information',
                ),
            ),
        ), 
        CheckBoxTileList(
            title: Text("Do you want to update your price?"),
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
            value: priceupdate_value,
            onChanged: (bool priceupdateValue) {
                setState(() {
                    priceupdate_value = priceupdateValue;
                });
            },
        ),
    ],
),
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Yours and the answer by another user below worked perfectly! Only difference i made was moving the Visible widget below the CheckboxListTile

Comment: You're welcome :) Yeah feel free to move them around :) Also check out my other comment (below the accepted answer) why I would advise you use this solution instead of the other one :D

Comment: This allows you to keep the space your TextInputFields would take allocated. Otherwise, if you add a button below your input field it will jump around) You can achieve this behaviour by adding maintainSize: true, (which forces you to add maintainAnimation: true, maintainState: true,) (handy if you want to have a button below your form fields)

Comment: Noted and thanks for the answers. what you referring to is essentially dependent on how i would implement in Native with `View.INVISIBLE` or `view.GONE`

Comment: yep exactly :D ;D